# Algorithm of combinations (problem with time and space)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

My algorithm generates combinations of elements. For example, having [A, B, C ] creates the following combinations [ A ], [ B ], [ C ], [ AB ], [ AC ], [ B, C ], [ ABC ].

Unfortunately for items too large too long and too much memory space, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemory` thrown. How can I fix?

```
public void combine() {
    this.findAllCombinations(combinazioneMassima);
}

private static class Node{
    int lastIndex = 0;
List<Elemento> currentList;
public Node(int lastIndex, List<Elemento> list) {
        this.lastIndex = lastIndex;
        this.currentList = list;
}
public Node(Node n) {
        this.lastIndex = n.lastIndex;
        this.currentList = new ArrayList<Elemento>(n.currentList);
}
}

public List<List<Elemento> > findAllCombinations(List<Elemento> combinazioni) {
    Date dataInizio = new Date();
    List<List<Elemento>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<Elemento>>();
    LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
    int n = combinazioni.size();
    ArrayList<Elemento> temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
    temp.add(combinazioni.get(0));
    queue.add(new Node(0, temp));
    // add all different integers to the queue once.
    for(int i=1;i<n;++i) {
            if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
            temp = new ArrayList<Elemento>();
            temp.add(combinazioni.get(i));
            queue.add(new Node(i, temp));
    }
    // do bfs until we have no elements
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = queue.remove();
            if(node.lastIndex+1 < n) {
                    Node newNode = new Node(node);
                    newNode.lastIndex = node.lastIndex+1;
                    newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(node.lastIndex+1));
                    queue.add(newNode);
            }
            for(int i=node.lastIndex+2;i<n;++i) {
                    if(combinazioni.get(i-1) == combinazioni.get(i)) continue;
                    // create a copy and add extra integer
                    Node newNode = new Node(node);
                    newNode.lastIndex = i;
                    newNode.currentList.add(combinazioni.get(i));
                    queue.add(newNode);
            }
            GestoreRegole gestoreRegole = new GestoreRegole();
            gestoreRegole.esegui(node.currentList);
    }
    Date dataF = new Date();
    long tempo = dataF.getTime() - dataInizio.getTime(); 
    logger.info ("durata genera combinazioni: " + tempo);
    return resultList;
```

Comment: I just want a hand to understand where the algorithm takes time or a better solution , different from mine

Comment: What do you do with the results after you have generated them? Your `combine` method seems.... useless.

Comment: After generating the combination , a method is called to see if the combination meets the rules . But the problem is in the generation of combinations that takes too long, how can I improve or I propose a better solution ?

Comment: With how many elements do you call this method?

Comment: Which method you mean?

Comment: This list: [A , B , C ]  how many elements does it contain when you have an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: He gives me java.lang.OutOfMemory when the list contains 256 items or more than 256 .

Comment: I think it should give you OutOfMemory much earlier, 256 is not feasible. 256 choose 128 is already ~10^75

Comment: @Pino What kind of "rules" is it that you are trying to match? Explaining the problem behind the code will helps us give you a better solution. It is quite likely that you can complete this in an entirely different way.

Comment: In practice, I apply a set of rules . Such that a given mass ( integer ) , if the mass of the compound generated is equal to that date , then add to the list of results .

Comment: I suggest that you add more context to your question, with more information about your chemical compounds problem. Adding a couple of inputs and outputs might also help.

Answer (score 2):

The Italian identifiers is making your code harder to understand, first of all.

There is only one way to solve your problem. **Don't store all of the combinations at once**.

Use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) instead. *Iterate* through the combinations one by one, and do the work that you need to do for each one. ***Without adding the combinations to a List***. Then throw the combination away and move on to the next one. There are many ways that you can [retrieve a specific combination](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62194/31562) without storing all combinations at once. That's something that you can iterate over.

When computing combinations it can often lead to a huge amount of possible combinations, which is why you need to *simplify the problem* as much as possible. Consider if there is any way you can group the combinations so that you can analyze many of them at once. I used several tricks like this that helped me greatly in [Analyzing Minesweeper Probabilities](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/analyzing-minesweeper-probabilities). I don't know enough of your use case to know whether or not you can simplify it, but I believe that you somehow can.

Comment: Hello , I do this when I call GestoreRegole.esegui . In practice, for each combination generated do I rate rules .

Comment: @Pino The problem is that you generate first. You should **not generate the combinations and store them in a list**. You should do the work that you are doing **without storing all the combinations**.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is generating all subsets.

> He gives me `java.lang.OutOfMemory` when the list contains 256 items or more than 256

Did you try to compute how big your set gets? It's \$2^{256}\$, i.e., about \$10^{77}\$, i.e.,

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

Go buy some more memory, but note that there are just \$10^{80}\$ atoms in your universe.

---

If you switched to some saner list sizes, like 40, you'll still get an OOM error as the set would be too big. But you could generate and process it lazily: Processing \$2^{40}\$ elements takes a while but is feasible.

For this you could use Guava's [Lists#cartesianProduct](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L446).

#### Review

I didn't write a real review as the code is not your (main) problem. But I'll do it if anyone requests.

Comment: hello how the cartesiaproduct ? I propose how to write code in Java ?

Comment: I have to downvote because I don't believe this solves the underlying problem. Storing all the possible combinations is the problem. Iterating is the answer (or my answer at least)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Who says that the [cartesian product](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/CartesianList.java) stores all the elements? It does not! +++ Still, it's a collection and therefore limited to `int`-valued size, but memory is not a problem here.

Comment: Sorry, it was unclear from the wording in your answer that the cartesian product was lazy. However, using the cartesian product does not help here as far as I can see. You can't have it return sets/lists of different size. Remember that the results should be `[A], [B], [C], [A B], [A C], [B C], [A B C].` That's not cartesian.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It's actually flattened \$\{\{A\}, \emptyset\} \times \{\{B\}, \emptyset\} \times \{\{C\}, \emptyset\}\$, but you're right, some more processing may be needed, e.g., dropping the empty set. No idea, if the OP needs a `List` or a `Set` (for sure, they don't need a `LinkedList`). And most probably, the processing will take too long anyway and the OP should do something else instead (XY problem).

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you use just too much memory when enumerating that many elements. You can try to increase the memory available to Java by using `-Xmx` or using array instead of Lists which may use less memory. But if you try to put that many elements in a list, you need much memory.

Since [a power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) has 2^n elements, **doubling the memory** will only make it possible to add **one** more element to the list, so it has only limited effect.

Why do you need such a list? For an algorithm you might try not use a brute-force algorithm which needs to enumerate all combinations.

Comment: I tried to increase the memory consumed and java netbeans but with few results . I need to generate all possible combinations of chemical compounds from some elements ( H , O, C , N )

Comment: Increasing the memory available will postpone the problem, not solve it. Changing between arrays and lists is a quite minimal difference, this problem needs to be solved in a different way.

Comment: Simon Andrè Forsberg, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I actually mentioned in the last paragraph that he should try to avoid enumerating all combinations. But if the problem is to enumerate all combinations in some data structure, these are some possibilities to increase the number of possible combinations  .