# Generic class to generate combinations

Tags: java, iteration

As junior java programmer I am working with Euler project and I would like to create a general purpose class which generates all the combinations from the `length` and number of `choosen` elements. The class returns a list of `boolean` arrays with length of `length`. Each array has `choosen` true value which highlight the chosen elements the others are false. I have a working solution (I mean it is tested to small numbers) but I wonder is there any opportunity to improve the performance or improve some other aspect. Here it is:

```
public static List<boolean[]> generate(int length, int choosen){
    List<boolean[]> variationList = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean[] actual = initArray(length, choosen);
    variationList.add(actual.clone());
    while(incrementArray(actual)) {
        variationList.add(actual.clone());
    }
    return variationList;
}


private static boolean[] initArray(int length, int choosen) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[length];
    for (int index=0; index<choosen; index++) {
        array[index] = true;
    }
    return array;
}

private static boolean incrementArray(boolean[] actual) {
    for(int index = actual.length-1; index > -1 ; index--) {
        if(actual[index]) {
            if(moveForward(actual, index)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean moveForward(boolean[] actual, int position) {
    if(position<actual.length-1 && !actual[position+1]) {
        actual[position] = false;
        actual[position+1] = true;
        copyBack(actual, position);
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

private static boolean copyBack(boolean[] actual, int position) {
    boolean answer = false;
    int delay = 2;
    for (int index = position+2; index<actual.length;index++) {
        if(actual[index]) {
            actual[index] = false;
            actual[position + delay] = true;
            delay++;
            answer = true;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

**Edit**

Euler project was only the motive I would like to find a way independently. My aim was produce all of the combinations (by the way my solution for the original problem needed them all (not just the number of them) but there is a workaround which no need combination at all). 
Some example of the method:

```
CombinationGenerator.generate(5, 1);
```

The result:

```
true false false false false
false true false false false
false false true false false
false false false true false
false false false false true
```

Invocation:

```
CombinationGenerator.generate(5, 3)
```

The result:

```
true true true false false
true true false true false
true true false false true
true false true true false
true false true false true
true false false true true
false true true true false
false true true false true
false true false true true
false false true true true
```

Comment: Related: [A specific combination](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62194/31562) (this might actually be exactly what you are looking for)

Comment: Which Project Euler assignment are you working on? Do you need the actual combinations or just the number of them?

Comment: Including several testcases would greatly improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `BitSet`

A `BitSet` is deliberately designed to be a memory efficient way to hold Boolean values.

It also has initialize methods (`clear` and `set`) already, so no need for `initArray`.  In combination with `nextSetBit` and `nextClearBit` (or the `previous` variants), those methods can replace `moveForward`.  And `copyBack` isn't necessary without `moveForward`.

The single increment `for` loop in `incrementArray` would not be necessary with a `BitSet`.  Again, the `nextSetBit` and `previousSetBit` methods would allow you to jump through multiple steps at once.

I haven't compared performance, but generally built-in methods are more efficient than custom methods.  The counter-argument here might be that a `BitSet` is more space efficient than time efficient.  Or that using the built-in methods involves algorithmic tradeoffs.  You'd have to test to see.

#### Nitpick

Choosen is not a word.  Although the base word is choose, the past participle is chosen with a single o.  But the variable doesn't really hold what has been chosen.  It holds a count of how many choices should be set to `true`.  The `BitSet` definition suggests that the best name for this is `cardinality`.  At least that's the name of the `BitSet` method.

`BitSet` also uses `size` to represent the total number of choices.  And uses `length` for something else.  Consider switching the parameter name `length` to `size` to match.  Not because `length` is a bad name, just inconsistent with `BitSet`.

Comment: Note that `BitSet` itself is a misnomer as it's actually a sort of compressed `Set<int>`. By no means it's a set of bits. Also `BitSet::cardinality` doesn't fit with collections as it corresponds with `Set::size`.

Comment: @maaartinus  The array used in this question is more like the view of a `BitSet` with a mixture of `true` and `false` values than like a collection of items.

Answer (score -2):

Try solving recursively where in each call you have to cases: appending 1 to an array and 0 (note that you do both each time). When you append 1, then you need to count if you have reached the chosen count or length, if not then call recursively on that array. Do the same for appending 0 except for you don't need to count if you exceeded choose limit.

Code is something like this (I use c++ but it is easily translatable to Java):

```
void gen_recursively(vector< vector<bool> > &combinations, vector<int> &current_combination, int len, int chosen) {
    if(current_combination.size() != len) {
        vector<int> current_with_0 = current_combination;
        current_with_0.push_back(0);
        gen_recursively(combinations, current_combination_with_0, len, chosen);

        vector<int> current_with_1 = current_combination;
        current_with_0.push_back(1);
        if(count_chosen(current_with_1)) {
            combinations.push_back(padd_with_zeros_at_end(current_with_1, len));
        } else {
            gen_recursively(combinations, current_combination_with_1, len, chosen);
        }
    } else {
        combinations.push_back(current_combination);
    }
}
```

Comment: C++ does things different than Java, so I'd consider your code example not applicable. The first part of your answer could be the start of a review, but as it stands it's more of an alternative implementation. We expect all answers to be a review of sorts and alternative implementations don't count if they're not part of a review.