# Finding the middle permutation

Tags: performance, ruby, array, combinatorics

This method finds all permutations of a string and stores them in a sorted array. It then returns the element in the middle of the array.

```
def middle_permutation(string)
  sorted = string.chars.to_a.permutation.map(&:join).sort
  sorted[sorted.length / 2 - 1]
end
```

For strings over 10+ characters this code is too slow. How can I speed it up?

Here are my tests. They pass, but I'd like it to be more efficient:

```
describe "Basic tests" do
  Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abc"),"bac")
  Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcd"),"bdca")
  Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdx"),"cbxda")
  Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdxg"),"cxgdba")
  Test.assert_equals(middle_permutation("abcdxgz"),"dczxgba")
end
```

Comment: You might be interested in this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62194/31562 . Even though I did it for combinations, it's possible to adapt it to work for permutations.

Comment: It's inefficient to actually make all the permutations. Can you count how many permutations start with a given letter without enumerating them? Now can you figure out which letter the middle permutation starts with? (Etcetera.)

Comment: It's always a good idea to get some rough guesstimates about the problem sizes involved before setting out on a solution. For your solution, for example, let's look at what happens with a string with, say, 15 characters. That's 1307674368000 (1.3 trillion) permutations. Even if you had a 5GHz CPU and even if it took only 1 clock cycle to generate one permutation, it would already take more than 4 minutes. And the array of permutations needs about 18TB of RAM. Sorting an array is O(n log n) comparisons (where n is the number of elements). Comparing two strings is O(n) (where n is the number of

Comment: … characters, so the `sort` is about O(n*n! log n!) in the length of the string, a function which looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bn+n!+Log%5Bn!%5D,+%7Bn,+1,+15%7D%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating every permutation is very expensive so you want to avoid doing that. There are some ways to handle this:

1) Sort the characters before you run your algorithm. That way you are sorting a few characters not billions of permutations.

2) If the string has an even number of characters (say `abcd`) remove the almost middle character (`b`) and rewrite as something like `'b' + 'acd'.reverse`

3) If the string has an odd number of characters (say `abcde`) you can remove the middle character (`c`) leaving `abde` and simplify the result as `'c' + middle_permutation('abcd')`

(3) Will always be followed by (2)

So you could rewrite your code as:

```
def middle_permutation2(string) 
  string = string.chars.sort.join("")
  return string if string.length <= 2

  if string.length.even?
    middle = string.length / 2 - 1
    remainder = string[0...middle] + string[middle+1..-1]
    string[middle] + remainder.reverse

  else
    middle    = string.length / 2
    remainder = string[0...middle-1] + string[middle+1..-1]
    string[middle] + string[middle-1] + remainder.reverse

  end

end
```