# Measuring performance of code using StopWatch

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, benchmarking

I have created a StopWatch class to measure the performance of any code. I use this StopWatch code in any of my multithreading projects as well.

```
public static class StopWatch {

    public static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();

    /**
     * Creates an instance of the timer and starts it running.
     */
    public static StopWatch getInstance() {
        return new StopWatch();
    }

    private long end = -1;
    private long interval = -1;
    private final long start;

    private StopWatch() {
        start = interval = currentTime();
    }

    /**
     * Returns in milliseconds the amount of time that has elapsed since the timer was created. If the
     * <code>stop</code> method has been invoked, then this returns instead the elapsed time between the creation of
     * the timer and the moment when <code>stop</code> was invoked.
     * 
     * @return duration it took
     */
    public long getDuration() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = start;
        final long endTime = isTimerRunning() ? currentTime() : end;

        result = nanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            Long oldValue = histogram.putIfAbsent(result, 1L);
            if (oldValue != null) {
                done = histogram.replace(result, oldValue, oldValue + 1);
            } else {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns in milliseconds the amount of time that has elapsed since the last invocation of this same method. If
     * this method has not previously been invoked, then it is the amount of time that has elapsed since the timer
     * was created. <strong>Note</strong> that once the <code>stop</code> method has been invoked this will just
     * return zero.
     * 
     * @return interval period
     */
    public long getInterval() {
        long result = 0;

        final long startTime = interval;
        final long endTime;

        if (isTimerRunning()) {
            endTime = interval = currentTime();
        } else {
            endTime = end;
        }

        result = nanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the timer from advancing. This has an impact on the values returned by both the
     * <code>getDuration</code> and the <code>getInterval</code> methods.
     */
    public void stop() {
        if (isTimerRunning()) {
            end = currentTime();
        }
    }

    /**
     * What is the current time in nanoseconds?
     * 
     * @return returns back the current time in nanoseconds
     */
    private long currentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime();
    }

    /**
     * This is used to check whether the timer is alive or not
     * 
     * @return checks whether the timer is running or not
     */
    private boolean isTimerRunning() {
        return (end <= 0);
    }

    /**
     * This is used to convert NanoSeconds to Milliseconds
     * 
     * @param nanoseconds
     * @return milliseconds value of nanoseconds
     */
    private long nanoToMilliseconds(final long nanoseconds) {
        return nanoseconds / 1000000L;
    }
}
```

I wanted to review this piece of code. Any suggestions or improvements I can make here?

Comment: Not code-related, but have you considered other microbenchmark tools such as [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper), or even something written by our very own [@rolfl, YAuB](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/yaub-yet-another-micro-benchmark)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few little things:

- A public static `getInstance()` method is commonly used in the singleton pattern. However, you always create a new `StopWatch`. At least you should name it to `createNewInstance()`, if you want to keep the method at all.
- Many of your comments are unnecessary. For example the comment before `isTimerRunning()` doesn't help to understand the code. If you are generating documentation, they might be required, if not, omit such comments.
- The `result` variable in `getInterval()` is not required. You can just return the result like this:

  ```
  return nanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);
  ```

  This saves you two lines of code and makes the code clearer. The same applies to `getDuration()`.
- by using the ternary if operator, you can shorten `getInterval()` a bit more:

  ```
  public long getInterval() {  
      final long startTime = interval;
      final long endTime = isTimerRunning() ? currentTime() : end;
      interval = endTime;
      return nanoToMilliseconds(endTime - startTime);;
  }
  ```

  The assignment `interval = endTime` now also happens when the `StopWatch` has already been stopped but this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is more than a stop watch: it's a stop watch with a *global* histogram. I suggest to split this to multiple classes:

- stop watch
- histogram
- stop watch with global histogram

Global state is usually undesirable. It would be better to have a stop watch factory class, that has a histogram, and provides stop watch instances that share that histogram. This would avoid global state.

Answer (score 1):

A small suggestion: in `nanoToMilliseconds()` you could write the value `1000000L` as `1_000_000L`. It doesn't change anything, except that it may be easier to read that this is a one followed by six zeroes.