# Series, Powers, and Benches

Tags: java, programming-challenge

#### Project Euler problem 48

> The series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 10^{10} = 10405071317\$.
>
> Find the last ten digits of the series, \$1^1 + 2^2 + 3^3 + ... + 1000^{1000}\$.

I made two different implementations of this problem, and added a benchmark, using rolfl's [UBench](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82439/yaub-micro-benchmark-follow-on) library.

The code:

```
public class ProjEuler48 {

    private static final int DIGITS = 10;
    private static final BigInteger MOD = BigInteger.TEN.pow(DIGITS);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int max = 1000;
        UBench bench = new UBench(ProjEuler48.class.getSimpleName());
        Predicate<BigInteger> predicate = value -> value.longValue() == 9110846700L;
        bench.addTask("Loops", () -> selfPowerSumMod(max, MOD), predicate);
        bench.addTask("Streams", () -> selfPowerSumModStreams(max, MOD), predicate);
        bench.report("RESULTS", bench.press(1000));
    }

    private static BigInteger selfPowerSumModStreams(int max, BigInteger mod) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, max)
                .parallel()
                .mapToObj(i -> BigInteger.valueOf(i))
                .map(bi -> bi.modPow(bi, MOD))
                .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add, BigInteger::add)
                .mod(mod);
    }

    public static BigInteger selfPowerSumMod(int max, BigInteger mod) {
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            sum = sum.add(selfPower(i)).mod(mod);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static BigInteger selfPower(int i) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        return result.modPow(result, MOD);
    }

}
```

Benchmark results on my machine:

> ```
> RESULTS
> =======
>
> Task ProjEuler48 -> Loops: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
>   Count    :     1000      Average  :   2.5267
>   Fastest  :   2.0137      Slowest  :  35.8331
>   95Pctile :   4.2812      99Pctile :   8.3346
>   TimeBlock : 4.718 2.646 2.801 2.280 2.191 2.128 2.119 2.124 2.132 2.127
>   Histogram :   936    53    10     0     1
>
> Task ProjEuler48 -> Streams: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
>   Count    :     1000      Average  :   0.8798
>   Fastest  :   0.3701      Slowest  :  37.6239
>   95Pctile :   2.7441      99Pctile :   5.5763
>   TimeBlock : 3.032 1.041 1.285 0.596 0.476 0.485 0.467 0.473 0.464 0.479
>   Histogram :   802    75    86    27     9     0     1
> ```

How is this code in terms of Project Euler, Java 8, performance and everything?

Answer (score 10):

This looks pretty good. A few changes I would make:

#### Performance

`10^10`, `20^20`, and all higher powers will always end in `0000000000`, which means they don't affect the sum. You should be able to get an approximately 10% performance improvement by not computing these powers. This would be easy to do in your loops case but would require a little syntactical cleverness in the streams way.

#### Magic Numbers

You have a magic number `9110846700L` in your code. It's not immediately clear what this is, especially if you are unfamiliar with the *UBench* library. This should be refactored into a magic number constant, in this case. [Further reading on this subject](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56375/eliminating-magic-numbers-when-is-it-time-to-say-no)

#### Static methods

Even for a program as simple as this, I would always shy away from putting your business logic in static methods. Obviously, in this case it isn't a problem, but for an application could grow at all, you will quickly regret it. [More further reading](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/01/29/static-methods-will-shock-you/)

#### Inconsistent method scope

One of your methods is `private`, the others are `public`. Again, this issue is not super relevant for such a short program, but allowing encapsulation to be broken starts to matter as soon a program reaches two classes.

Comment: Very easy to do on the streams as well: `.filter(i -> i % 10 != 0)`

Comment: I said "a little" syntactical cleverness ;)