# Find k-th smallest index

Tags: c++, performance, statistics

in an MCMC procedure I am repeatedly (100,000+ times) running the following function to find the kth order statistic. I ran a profiler and noticed this function was most expensive. I am looking for a way to optimize this code for speed. The reason I think it can be done faster is because I do not want find the kth largest value, but the index of the kth largest value. However, now I'm effectively looping twice through the vector `x`, which seems inefficient to me.
The code below is an example, in practice I use R and Rcpp to run the code. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\c++\armadillo-7.950.1\include\armadillo"

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int qSelectIdxC(arma::vec& x, const int k) {

    // ARGUMENTS
    // x: vector to find k-th largest element in
    // k: k-th statistic to look up

    // safety copy since nth_element modifies in place
    arma::vec y(x.memptr(), x.n_elem);

    // partially sorts y.
    std::nth_element(y.begin(), y.begin() + k, y.end());

    // the k-th largest value
    const double kthValue = y(k);

    // find and return the index of the k-th largest value;
    int idxK = std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), kthValue) - x.begin();
    return idxK;

}

int main() {

    vec test0 = regspace<vec>(0, 10); // 0, 1, ..., 10
    int ans0 = qSelectIdxC(test0, 5); // returns 5

    vec test1(100, fill::randu);
    int ans1 = qSelectIdxC(test1, 50);

    cout << "ans0" << ans0;
    cout << "ans1" << ans1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the kth smallest/largest value you do not need to sort all values! Simply keep track of the k smallest/largest encountered values in a (sorted) buffer. This will take your run time from O(nlog(n)) to O(nlog(k)). And will also avoid the unnecessary copy and iteration, simply keep the index with k.

The following pseudocode illustrates the algorithm

```
template<typename It>
It min_k(It first, It last, int k){
   auto cmp_it_values = [](It lt, It rt){ return *lt < *rt;};
   auto max_copy = std::min<long>(k, std::distance(first, last));
   auto start_it = first;
   std::advance(start_it, max_copy);

    k++; // k == 0 has to return smallest one element.
    std::vector<It> k_smallest;
    k_smallest.reserve(k+1);
    for(auto it = first; it != start_it; ++it){
        k_smallest.push_back(it);
    }
    std::sort(k_smallest.begin(), k_smallest.end(), cmp_it_values);

    for(auto it = start_it; it != last; ++it){
        if(k_smallest.empty() || *it < *k_smallest.back()){
            auto insertion_point = std::lower_bound(k_smallest.begin(), k_smallest.end(), 
                                                    it, cmp_it_values);
            k_smallest.insert(insertion_point, it);
            if(k_smallest.size() > k){
                k_smallest.pop_back(); // Remove the largest value
            }
        }
    }    
    return k_smallest.back(); // The iterator to the min(k, n) smallest value 
}
```

The above has O(nklog(k)) worst case and O(n + log(k)) best case behaviour. You can improve the worst case by using a max heap for k_smallest instead of a vector. This would have the promised O(nlog(k)) run time. I leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)

And you should read this [`using namespace std;` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

You can see from the benchmark here: https://ideone.com/B81Hs4 that the code above is twice as fast as your original code for the given values (you need to test with typical values for your application to verify) and the heap version is even faster.

Comment: @Incomputable I did something very similar in Java: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116469/print-the-n-longest-lines-in-a-file this was the fastest method of all the benchmarked ones.

Comment: At a glance, it appears that the `using namespace` declarations could be reduced in scope (to within `main()`) as a first step to removing them completely, which may help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to understand your code and it certainly looks a lot faster! However, I noticed that if I change `std::vector<int> v(10000);` to `std::vector<int> v(100);` the values of `ans1` no longer match between the methods. Am I misunderstanding something about the method?

Comment: @Vandenman If you change the number of items to 100 and then ask for the 500th smallest number, it's a question of denition what you should return. Your algorithm returned `0`.  I had a bug in my code, I've fixed it now. It will return the largest number if k > n.

Comment: Apologies, that's not what I meant. In my usage the index is (should never be) out of bounds. Many thanks for the update though, I will have another look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a very similar problem and believe i found an efficient solution, that is even better when done repeatedly.

In my case we wanted to know the k largest values of an array without changing the array.

The approach you took was that you copied the data then sorted that and searched agaion in the original data. What is better is to sort references to the data

```
// Lets assume data is filled
std::vector<double> data;
std::vector<double*> dataPtr;
dataPtr.reserve(data.size()
for (size_t index = 0; index < data.size(); ++index) {
    dataPtr.emplace_back(std::next(data.data(), index));
}
```

What you can do now is sorting dataPtr via an overloaded comparison operator

```
auto lessPtr= [] (const double* first, const double* second) { return *first < *second; };
std::nth_element(dataPtr.begin(), dataPtr.begin() + k, dataPtr.end(), lessPtr)
```

Now the index of the k-largest element would simply be

```
std::distance(data.data(), dataPtr[k]);
```

The real beauty about this approach is that it is not only more efficient if you do it once, as you can ommit the second search over the array. It gets even better once you have to repeatedly search, as you can allocate the dataPtr array once and save the allocation/copy of the temporary array during consecutive searches.

If I borrow from @Emily L.

```
template<typename It>
size_t min_k(It first, It last, int k){
    auto cmp_it_values = [](It lt, It rt){ return **lt < **rt; } // double dereference as we work with pointers to the data    
    std::nth_element(first, std::next(first, k), last, cmp_it_values);
    return static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(*first, *std::next(first, k)); 
}
```

Comment: Your method has to create a vector of pointers to all elements in the original data so essentially it's the same as a copy of the original. My code works with iterators into the original vector which has the same effect but doesn't need to make a full vector of pointers to all elements.

Comment: @EmilyL. you are both right and wrong ;) For a single run your code is undoubtely more efficient (yet mine is still better than the original one) However, for every consequtive run mine beats yours as it does not require a single allocation. Given that the OP claims he runs the function 100,000+ times and he currently used the additional memory anyway, my solution is a simple sort without any further allocations and is therefore more efficient than yours, which requires some depending on the distribution of the data

Comment: https://ideone.com/B81Hs4 yours runs twice as slow as the original or did I misunderstand your algo? Also op said they run it 100k+, they did however not say that the data is the same each run and only k differs. If thats the case, sure make a vector of iterators, sort it and just repeatedly lookup in the vector.

Comment: @EmilyL. What i had in mind is more like this https://ideone.com/tLI4dr However, it seems that the indirection with the dereference of the pointers is indeed slower